# Sqlite check if number is integer

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to select a every field when a certain equation produces an `integer` which means a number that has no decimals. How can you do that in Sqlite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want rows with out a decimal:

```
select 
   "(" + DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROW_ID + " - 1)/4 + 1" as field
from 
   table
where 
   field not like '%.%'
```

EDIT:

Based on comments the calculated field has been added.  SQLite supports using alias' in where clauses, so this should work for you.

Comment: what if did a calculation such as `"(" + DatabaseOpenHelper.KEY_ROW_ID + " - 1)/4 + 1"` will that work too?

Comment: I got it, i was trying to compare if that equation was an integer. I ended up comparing the original one to the one parsed in ROUND() to test if they are the same. Thank you anyways. :)

Comment: @DannyWatts Glad I could help.  Dont forget upvoting and answering, its how we show thanks around here. :)